# Add new data to existing collection in mongo in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need two to add new items to the existing data in mongo db.

This is mongo db I have the following data.

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("53ce11e7d0881d32d9fa935f"),
    "name" : "massive riots",
    "lastFeachedTime" : "Jul 15, 2014 12:55:27 PM"
  }
```

Here I have to find the data based on name and the I have to add another two items two it.

Here is my code.

```
     DBObject queryObject = new BasicDBObject().append("name", keyword);
        if (null == newFetchTime) {

        }
        DBObject updateObject = new BasicDBObject();
        updateObject.put("nextPageToken", nextPageToken);
        updateObject.put("prevPageToken", prevPageToken);
        Utils utils = new Utils();
        DBCollection collection = utils.getStaging().getCollection("test");     
        collection.update(queryObject, updateObject, true, false);
```

But I am do update the existing value get removed and the new data get added.

Can any one tell me how to add the items to the existing data in mongo db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator in your update. This allows the specified fields to be altered without affecting any of the existing fields in the document, unless the specified field exists in which case that field is overwritten:

```
    DBObject update = new BasicDBObject(
        "$set", new BasicDBObject()
            .append("nextPageToken",nextPageToken)
            .append("prevPageToken",prevPageToken)
    );
```

Works out to the equivalent in shell:

```
{ "$set" : { "nextPageToken" : nextPageToken , "prevPageToken" : prevPageToken }}
```